# git add . crashes and git commit -a crashes

Tags: linux, git

I created a new repo on my bitbucket account and cloned it using

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:themonkeymixer/zte-warp-cm9.git`

I add one folder to the repo, containing 21 files (60KB total).

I then issue `git add .` This works (this time)

Then `git commit -a -m 'added initial folder'`

The computer completely freezes and the computer is non-responsive until `ctrl +c` is pressed then a few minutes later it unlocks

Any ideas?

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
```

also i have tries adding the cm9 source as individual folders it appears to randomly crash when empty folders are in the source

however i added files called README with the text this is the README

it still crashes

Comment: Which version of git do you have installed?

Comment: After adding your files, try running `git commit -m 'initial commit' --verbose`, to see where git is hanging / what it's doing.

Comment: `git commit -a -m` will only commit the changes to all *tracked* files. As you're adding a new folder, it won't commit any of the new files in that folder.

Comment: Are you sure you just don't have heaps of files or very deep folder hierarchies?